# No WebApplicationContext found: not in a DispatcherServlet request

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I have a Spring application. For some reasons, I have a standard servlet and I need that servlet to be able to access to some spring beans (I know that this is not ideal, and I will be looking for something better in the future).

in Web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <description>Tunnel servlet.</description>
    <servlet-name>Tunnel</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        com.something.GuacamoleController
    </servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Tunnel</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/path</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and GuacamoleController

```
public class GuacamoleController extends GuacamoleHTTPTunnelServlet {

    @Override
    protected GuacamoleTunnel doConnect(HttpServletRequest request)
            throws GuacamoleException {

        WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext = RequestContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(request);

        [...]
    }
}
```

But it is throwing this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: not in a DispatcherServlet request?
```

How can I make this case a DispatcherServlet request ?

I need the Web Application Context so I can manually access to a instance of a service with getBean method

Comment: If you're working with Spring MVC, why are you creating your own servlets?

Comment: The situation requires so. The best would be to convert this servlet ( http://guac-dev.org/doc/gug/writing-you-own-guacamole-app.html#idm139993934478752 ) to a Spring Controller. It would solve the problem too.

Comment: *The situation requires so*. Well, that's your exact problem and that's what you should ask.

Comment: AL already did, I waited for three days and no reply was given. I have to fix this problem to make some test. Could be possible to focus in the question ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not in the context of a `DispatcherServlet`, you are rolling in your own `Servlet` implementation.

You *may* be in the context of a `ContextLoaderListener`. Use

```
WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(request.getServletContext());
```

to get the `WebApplicationContext` loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener`. If it doesn't exist, the method will throw an exception.